# Find the minimum number of moves to get a "Good" string

Tags: c++, string, algorithm

A string is called to be good if and only if "**All the distinct characters in String are repeated the same number of times**".

Now, Given a string of length n, what is the minimum number of changes we have to make in this string so that string becomes good.

**Note :** We are only allowed to use lowercase English letters, and we can change any letter to any other letter.

**Example :** Let String is yyxzzxxx

Then here answer is 2.

**Explanation :** One possible solution yyxyyxxx. We have changed 2 'z' to 2 'y'. Now both 'x' and 'y' are repeated 4 times.

**My Approach :**

1. Make a hash of occurrence of all 26 lowercase letters.
2. Also find number of distinct alphabets in string.
3. Sort this hash array and start checking if length of string is divisible by number of distinct characters.If yes then we got the answer.
4. Else reduce distinct characters by 1.

But its giving wrong answers for some results as their may be cases when removing some character that has not occur minimum times provide a good string in less moves.

So how to do this question.Please help.

Constraints : Length of string is up to 2000.

My Approach :

```
string s;
    cin>>s;
    int hash[26]={0};

    int total=s.length();
    for(int i=0;i<26;i++){
        hash[s[i]-'a']++;
    }
    sort(hash,hash+total);
    int ans=0;
    for(int i=26;i>=1;i--){
        int moves=0;
        if(total%i==0){
            int eachshouldhave=total/i;
            int position=26;
            for(int j=1;j<26;j++){
                if(hash[j]>eachshouldhave && hash[j-1]<eachshouldhave){
                    position=j;
                    break;
                }
            }
            int extrasymbols=0;
            //THE ONES THAT ARE BELOW OBVIOUSLY NEED TO BE CHANGED TO SOME OTHER SYMBOL
            for(int j=position;j<26;j++){
                extrasymbols+=hash[j]-eachshouldhave;
            }
            //THE ONES ABOVE THIS POSITION NEED TO GET SOME SYMBOLS FROM OTHERS
            for(int j=0;j<position;j++){
                moves+=(eachshouldhave-hash[j]);
            }
            if(moves<ans)
            ans=moves;
        }
        else
        continue;
    }
```

Comment: Show us how you implemented your approach.

Comment: @legends2k I edited it.Sorry

Comment: Please post a link to the source of this problem, so that we know it's not from a currently active programming competition.  Thanks!

Comment: @j_random_hacker: is that against the rules? I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: @j_random_hacker It was a interview question .So i dont have any such link

Comment: @Groo It is highly unethical to ask a question from active competition (as others do it by their own, and it gives you unfair advantage). Most 'algorithm' tag participants are unwilling to answer such questions, and will vote to close them.

Comment: Asking on a public Q&A site actually gives everyone the answers, doesn't it? Also, the question is perfectly within the SO format: it's not off topic, it doesn't ask for tools recommendation, it includes an attempt to solve it, it doesn't ask for opinions. You can argue that many answers on SO can be utilized for unethical purposes.

Comment: @Groo: It gives everyone who happens to be repeatedly hitting F5 on stackoverflow.com the answers.  We can't catch all unethical uses of SO, but I don't think that's a reason not to try.  The OP gets points for describing their solution attempt, but I remain sceptical.  I also see that s/he has asked 9 questions, and not voted once.

Comment: @user3840069: In your solution you miss that some letter count should be reduced to `0`.

Comment: @Jarod42 What ? I didnt get you

Comment: Imagine that `total == 27`, and `i == 1`, and each letter appears less than 27, then your algorithm count the number of moves to set each letter to `27` whereas only one letter should be increase to this number.

Comment: Please you can give movelist about what we can do.                          -We can change letters.                                                  -Can we remove?                                                          -Can we add?                                                           -Do we have any shortcut move (like changing letter -> remove+add at one move)

Comment: @oknsnl By changing i mean we can replace a single character by some other character.We cant decrease or increase length of string.

Answer (score 0):

Following should fix your implementation:

```
std::size_t compute_change_needed(const std::string& s)
{
    int count[26] = { 0 };

    for(char c : s) {
        // Assuming only valid char : a-z
        count[c - 'a']++;
    }
    std::sort(std::begin(count), std::end(count), std::greater<int>{});
    std::size_t ans = s.length();
    for(std::size_t i = 1; i != 27; ++i) {
        if(s.length() % i != 0) {
            continue;
        }
        const int expected_count = s.length() / i;
        std::size_t moves = 0;
        for(std::size_t j = 0; j != i; j++) {
            moves += std::abs(count[j] - expected_count);
        }
        ans = std::min(ans, moves);
    }
    return ans;
}
```